# How to apply @media for css attribute that are set via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

My website is responsive, I've set a CSS attribute via jQuery, But there is a problem, when I use of `@media` (for mobile display), that attribute does not change, why ?

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="test">foo</div>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
$(".test").css({'margin' : '20px'});
```

**CSS code:**

```
@media (max-width: 599px){
   .test {margin: 10px;}
}
```

Why `@media` does not works? And how it works ?

It should be noted that the output is always `margin : 20px` (for all `@media` size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because JavaScript, and by further extension jQuery, adds CSS styles inline, so they take precedence over any styles that are applied in your stylesheet.

Use another class rather than using `.css()`:

```
.margin{
  margin: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 599px){
   .test {margin: 10px;}
}
```

And then add the class using jQuery and [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
$(".test").addClass('margin');
```

Comment: Thanks, worked correctly, but why my question got -1 votedown ? do you know ?

Comment: @Sajad Glad to have helped. I'm afraid not, best not to take it too personally.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test {border:1px solid #000}
@media (max-width: 1024px){
   .test {margin: 20px;}
}
@media (max-width: 599px){
   .test {margin: 10px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="test">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to overwrite javascript CSS (applied with jQuery) with css CSS. CSS applied by javascript has always priority.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery applies it's css on the element, which has a higher importance than your class in css...if you really need to, you can add `.test {margin: 10px !important;}` in that media query of yours. hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify a @media type, for example :

```
@media screen and (max-width 768px) {
//Your declaration here
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If no media type is provided, the styles in the block are applied for all media types.